# read/write/execute to pl/sql grants

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema, plsql

For a current task and future references, I am wondering how pl/sql grants (select, insert, update, delete, references, alter, index, all) are categorized from a read/write/execute or read/read-write/read-write-execute point of view? A lot of end users or non-dba folks tend to use the later language when asking for access or grant privileges where I work. Any feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: Is the code in the same schema as the tables?

Answer (score 2):

**Read:** `READ`.

Not `SELECT`. Forget `SELECT`. `SELECT` privilege allows users to run `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`, which modifies the metadata in the database blocks (not the user data) and locks the affected rows.

`READ` privilege is available starting with 12c.

**Write:** `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

**Execute:** `EXECUTE`

For the rest ([Object Privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3__BGBCIIEG)), most people do not even know about them and can happily live without them.

Answer (score 1):

> A lot of end users or non-dba folks tend to use the later language when asking for access or grant privileges where I work.

Question: Why are "end users and non-dba folks" getting *direct access* to the database?

They should not need it. They should be going through an Application that enables them to do what they need to do, preferably using a dedicated account to connect to the database on their behalf.

To actually *answer* your question:

- "Read" (User-Speke) => "select" (DBA-Speke)
- "Write" => "delete", "insert", "update"
- "Execute" => "execute"

There are a few others you *might* need (like "usage") but, for the most part, I don't think you'll need them.  YMMV.

See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html

Create Roles and grant [object] privileges to those Roles.  Then grant those Roles to your Users.  Assuming you have different Environments (Production, Test, etc.) use the same Role names in each Environment, but tailor the granted privileges appropriately (no User "update" access in Production, for example).